# Does intellij "find in files" support filter by full path?

Tags: intellij-idea

Say my project has the following structure

```
.
├── foo1
│   └── b
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
└── foo2
    └── b
        ├── file3
        └── file4
```

I have directories named `b` under both `foo1` and `foo2`. When using "Find in Files", can I specifically search for files within any `b` directory (i.e., targeting `foo1/b` and `foo2/b` paths)?

Currently, "file mask" option seems to only apply to file names instead of the full path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found "Find in path action should accept file path mask" feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106216/Find-in-path-action-should-accept-file-path-mask

looks like a workaround is "creating a custom scope in "find in file""